# Python - Download file not working

Tags: python, authentication, download, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to download a file/read the page content. The url is authenticated through **Siteminder** authentication. I'm using the below code, but I'm getting

> 401: Authentication Error

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
url = "https://myurl.com/blah..."
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, 'myuserID', 'myPassword')
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=context).read()
print(response.text)
```

I also tried below with `requests`, but I'm getting same error.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

url = "https://myurl.com/blah..."
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('url', SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
response = s.get(url, params=None, verify=True, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('myuserID', 'myPassword'), timeout=None)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

I'm using Windows 10, with Python 3.5.

But if I run it in UNIX system, then it's working, I can download the file:

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --no-check-certificate --user=myuserID --password=myPassword 'https://myurl.com/blah...'
```

What's wrong in the python code?

**Update:**
If I use below code using cookies then 1 html file is downloaded: And when I open the html file in IE then again it's asking for credentials, and then the exact file is downloaded.

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar

url = "https://myurl.com/blah..."
username = 'myuserID'
password = 'myPassword'

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')]
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'user': username, 'password': password}).encode("utf-8")
print(params)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
    urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url, params).read()
print(page)
```

The html is as below:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">
This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request.<BR><BR>You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below.
<FORM NAME="AUTOSUBMIT" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ACTION="https://myurl.com/blah...">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SMPostPreserve" VALUE="gPcBiwAFuJyNjkpY2Lq/i3Iq80qHAGVxfmNyp3VohPbmmfdNGf5bEhuAZXmqUWJ+ftkJ4uZvFjrnDf+sGAm13m5CDGTljCCF">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Continue">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Does this URL use Basic authentication or Ntlm?

Comment: When I hit the URL in IE, it prompts for user ID and password. After providing credentials, the file is downloaded. It's an intranet web application where users have limited access.

Comment: Then try this using requests: `s.get(url, auth=('myuserID', 'myPassword'), verify=True)`

Comment: No, it's not working, I'm getting SSL error:
`requests.exceptions.SSLError:  HTTPSConnectionPool(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))`.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `verify=false` instead?

Comment: @OmarEinea, if I use `verify=False` then I'm getting the earlier error as `<H1>401: Access Denied</H1>`